# Prove the linear transformations to be independent when their ranges are disjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a question of *Linear Algebra by Friedberg*. It asks you to prove that if $T$ and $U$ are nonzero linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, then they form a linearly independent set provided

$Range(T)\cap Range(U)=\{0\}$
Being a beginner who's self-studying, I can't make out how to use the above condition in my proof. Some guidance would be helpful.

Comment: A good start is to ask yourself what a linear dependence on T and U is.

Comment: @MatthewTowers That $T=kU$ for some scalar $k$?

Comment: That's right. Try evaluating at an element of the domain. You're looking for a contradiction.

Comment: You need to decide whether you're going to write the linear dependence as T=kU or as aT+bU=0. Doing both is just confusing you.

Comment: Yes got it. That you for the interest.

Comment: See here: https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_2-2-13?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $cT = U$ for some constant $c \neq 0$. Since $T \neq 0$, there is some $x \in V$ and some $0 \neq y \in W$ such that $T(x) = y \neq 0$. But then it follows that

$$y = \frac{1}{c} c y = \frac{1}{c} U(x) = U(\frac{1}{c} x) \in \operatorname{Range}(U),$$

where we have used the linearity of $U$. This means $y \in \operatorname{Range}(U) \cap \operatorname{Range}(T)$, which is a contradiction.